# JSON for HTML application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm accessing JSON-stored text in my HTML application, using JQuery. (`$.getJSON()`). Is there any easy way to display JSON text in HTML, instead of repeating

`$.getJSON( "en.json", function( data ) {$("data.x").appendTo(".inner");});`

every time I want to display something? By centralizing the process somewhere?

Thank you

Comment: which part you are repeating ?

Comment: If you need to load it then you need to... load it. What exactly do you mean by "centralizing" it?

Comment: I mean is there any shorter way of doing this? Sorry if "centralizing" wasn't an apt word. Do I need to copy+paste the same statements everywhere I need to display text on the page?

Comment: Are you making multiple requests using same `$.getJSON( "en.json", function( data ) {$("data.x").appendTo(".inner");});` ? Or are there other URL's that you are requesting?

Comment: I'm requesting the same file multiple times, except different strings each time

Comment: @BillyBob You want to create a function that takes parameters.  That's one way of avoiding code duplication.  Functions are covered in any basic JavaScript tutorial -- it is fundamental basic knowledge.

Comment: Ahh yes, thank you! Also, can you please tell me why this line doesn't work: `$.getJSON( "C:/xampp/htdocs/csr/lang/en.json", function( data ) {$(".inner").append(data.age);});` ? The file is in the right location. What is the error in it?

Comment: You do this statement the first time with the whole data , store in a global object , and use it from there whenever you want to access it. Remember to clone the object. You don't want to mess with original data copy . So clone it so if any changes you want to have your actual copy doesn't get changed